# Узнать имя домена из приложения Ruby-on-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

Имеется:
Приложение на ruby на фреймворке Ruby-on-Rails

Требуется:
Узнать доменное имя, на котором развернуто приложение

Пояснение: т.е. я разрабатываю плагин для redmine и мне нужно отправить на сторонний сервер полный адрес моего приложения. Как я могу его получить

Комментарий:
Я недавно только перешел на ruby, до этого работал на php, там есть интересный массив `$_SERVER`, из которого можно получить эту информацию, а как это следать в Руби

Comment: Попробуйте `Socket.gethostname`.

Answer (score 0):

Если это нужно в контроллере, можно воспользоваться методом [`request.host`](https://rdoc.info/docs/rails/6.0.2.1/ActionDispatch%2FHttp%2FURL:host).